# Can we create graviton particle or gravitational wave?

Tags: quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, carrier-particles

Can we create [graviton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton) particle or [gravitational wave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave)?

I want to know if we able to generate graviton particle out of some energy. Is it theoretically possible? And could we generate gravitational waves, attract some rock by gravity force?

If it possible, suggest we want to lift some 10 kg rock up from ground, how many watt of energy needed for this graviton generator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't gravitons be created in traditional particle accelerators?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/192068/)