# What's the relationship between classical gravitational waves and gravitons?

Tags: general-relativity, quantum-gravity, gravitational-waves, ligo, carrier-particles

LIGO have detected gravitational waves, why we are still far away from detecting gravitations?

how to understand the statement below?

> A classical wave may be considered to be a coherent
>   superposition of a large number of gravitons.

Comment: There isn't one: gravitational waves are a prediction of a classical theory -- GR -- and have nothing at all to do with the quantization of gravity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prospects for detection of gravitons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235603)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shift your question to QED: Detecting the particle nature of light is a complete different task from detecting light in general.

When people say Graviton they usually mean the particle structure of the theory (quantized theory). Like in Electromagnetism where it was discovered that light in fact behaves like particles and that EM is the classical limit of QED.

We dont know yet if gravity is quantized, but many people believe it for many good reasons.